# All data in a table with relationships, empty arrays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, model

I have the Post, Category and Tag models with their relationships and working well in other inquiries.

If I get the categories and tags of a post specifically, the data returns correctly me.

```
$post = Post::with('categorias', 'etiquetas')->find($id)->toArray();
```

With <kbd>Post::has</kbd> only shows data Posts that do have categories, at least I understand it, so that does not help me.

```
$posts = Post::has('category')->get()->toArray();
```

But when I try to get all posts with their corresponding categories and tags for each post, I get a data array with an array post more empty categories and labels. As I can make the array comes with its data.

```
$posts = Post::with('categorias', 'etiquetas')->get()->toArray();
```

---

```
1 => 
array (size=11)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'titulo' => string 'A title once again' (length=18)
  'subtitulo' => string '' (length=0)
  'contenido' => string 'And the post body follows.' (length=26)
  'created_at' => string '2015-04-09 13:19:12' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2015-05-04 13:44:25' (length=19)
  'user_id' => null
  'publicacion' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
  'activo' => string '0' (length=1)
  'categorias' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      4 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
  'etiquetas' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I auto answer my question.

The query works correctly:

```
$posts = Post::with('categorias', 'etiquetas')->get()->toArray();
```

In laravel 4, the dumper does not go so far as to display data relationships, so you have to get there otherwise.

```
dd($posts[1]['categorias']);
```

---

```
array (size=5)
0 => 
array (size=3)
  'id' => string '7' (length=1)
  'nombre' => string 'CATEGORIA1' (length=13)
  'pivot' => 
    array (size=2)
      'post_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'categoria_id' => string '7' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=3)
  'id' => string '8' (length=1)
  'nombre' => string 'CATEGORIA2' (length=17)
  'pivot' => 
    array (size=2)
      'post_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'categoria_id' => string '8' (length=1)
2...
```